# set the insert order of a many to many sqlalchemy flask app sqlite db

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**My Goal**
I want to record the order of manys upon insert of data to my table (e.g. Clump-see tables below).  
The orderinglist module is really great, but how do i apply it to the intermediary table (named clump_syntaxs) between my many-to-many?  anyone done this before and have a good example?

**problem re-stated**
How do i apply ordering upon insert to my many to many.  
Everything I try using the intermediary table-clump_syntaxs table crashes (sorry for the weird names!).

The following code (reduced for brevity) works! except that it only allows for a syntax to have a unique position (instead of a position for every Clump instance), and I am guessing I need the position variable to be on the clump_syntaxs table.
all tables are sqlite

**my intermediary table**

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.orderinglist import ordering_list
clump_syntaxs = db.Table('clump_syntaxs',
    db.Column('syntax_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('syntax.id')),
    db.Column('clump_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('clump.id')),
)
```

**add a clump and order syntax tables**

```
class Clump(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    syntaxs = db.relationship('Syntax', secondary=clump_syntaxs,
        backref=db.backref('clumps', lazy='dynamic'),order_by="Syntax.position",
                            collection_class=ordering_list('position'))

class Syntax(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    jobs = db.relationship('Jobs',lazy='dynamic', backref='jobhistory')
    position = db.Column(db.Integer)
    #Jobs table not included
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should move `position` field to the intermediary table `ClumpSyntax`, and take advantage of `association_proxy()` in `Clump` table.

```
import sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

class Syntax(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    jobs = db.relationship('Jobs',lazy='dynamic', backref='jobhistory')
    #position = db.Column(db.Integer)  # moved to ClumpSyntax
    #Jobs table not included 

class ClumpSyntax(db.Model):
    syntax_id = db.Column('syntax_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('syntax.id'))
    syntax = relationship(Syntax)
    clump_id = db.Column('clump_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('clump.id')) 
    position = db.Column(db.Integer)

    # this constructor is very necessary !
    def __init__(self, syntax =None):
        self.syntax = syntax 

class Clump(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    _syntaxs = db.relationship('ClumpSyntax', 
                               order_by=[ClumpSyntax.position],
                               collection_class=ordering_list('position'))
    syntaxs = association_proxy('_syntaxs','syntax')
```

My similar request was satisfied quite well by this way, based on the article [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292726/how-to-properly-use-association-proxy-and-ordering-list-together-with-sqlalchemy) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/S4_8PeRBNJw). You can test it by code like below:

```
    session= some_code_to_get_db_session()
    syn1= Syntax()
    syn2= Syntax()
    syn3= Syntax()
    session.add(syn1)
    session.add(syn2)
    session.add(syn3)

    clump= Clump()
    session.add(clump)

    clump.syntaxs.append(syn1)
    clump.syntaxs.append(syn2)
    clump.syntaxs.append(syn3)

    session.commit()

    session.query(ClumpSyntax).count()  # print out 3
    session.query(Syntax).count()       # print out 3
```