# Flask SQLAlchemy Many to Many association object error

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a project using python 3.4, Flask and SQLAlchemy that is based on project management. I have the following classes that need to be linked to each other in a many to many relationship. User and Project modules are functioning as expected individually.
The user model code is included below

```
class User(db.Model):
__tablename__='users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key =True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(80))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(80))
    email = db.Column(db.String(35), unique =True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique= True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    organisation_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('organisations.id'))
    organisation = db.relationship('Organisation', backref='users')
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean)

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, email, username, password, organisation_id, is_admin=False):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.email = email
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.password = password
        self.is_admin = is_admin
        self.username = username
        organisation_id = organisation_id
```

the code for the project is

```
class Project(db.Model):
    __tablename__ ="projects"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    owner = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    start = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    finish = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    cycle_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('reportingcycles.id'))
    cycle= db.relationship('ReportingCycle', backref='project')
    org_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('organisations.id'))
    organisation= db.relationship('Organisation', backref='project')
    status = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    users = db.relationship("UserProject", backref="project")

    def __init__(self, code, name, description, owner, start, finish, cycle, organisation, status):
        self.code = code
        self.name = name
        self.owner = owner
        self.description = description
        self.start = start
        self.finish = finish
        self.status = status
        self.org_id= organisation.id
        self.cycle_id= cycle.id
```

I have created an association object as per the SQLAlchemy tutorial in this link [Association Object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object/)
The code for the association class is

```
class UserProject(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_project'
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id'), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

    user = db.relationship("User", backref="project_assocs")
```

When I tried to test this relationship in command line by typing the following code

```
prj = Project.query.first()
usr = User.query.first()
asso = UserProject(role_id =1)
asso.user = usr
prj.users.append(asso)
```

I get the following error on trying to commit these changes to the DB.

> /home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/crud.py:692:
>   SAWarning: Column 'user_project.project_id' is marked as a member of
>   the primary key for table 'user_project', but has no Python-side or
>   server-side default generator indicated, nor does it indicate
>   'autoincrement=True' or 'nullable=True', and no explicit value is
>   passed.  Primary key columns typically may not store NULL. Note that
>   as of SQLAlchemy 1.1, 'autoincrement=True' must be indicated
>   explicitly for composite (e.g. multicolumn) primary keys if
>   AUTO_INCREMENT/SERIAL/IDENTITY behavior is expected for one of the
>   columns in the primary key. CREATE TABLE statements are impacted by
>   this change as well on most backends.   util.warn(msg) Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "", line 1, in    File
>   "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py",
>   line 237, in **get**
>       return self.impl.get(instance_state(instance), dict_)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py",
>   line 584, in get
>       value = self.callable_(state, passive)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py",
>   line 557, in _load_for_state
>       return self._emit_lazyload(session, state, ident_key, passive)   File "", line 1, in    File
>   "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py",
>   line 635, in _emit_lazyload
>       result = q.all()   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py",
>   line 2703, in all
>       return list(self)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py",
>   line 2854, in **iter**
>       self.session._autoflush()   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 1375, in _autoflush
>       util.raise_from_cause(e)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 203, in raise_from_cause
>       reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 187, in reraise
>       raise value   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 1365, in _autoflush
>       self.flush()   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 2139, in flush
>       self._flush(objects)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 2259, in _flush
>       transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py",
>   line 66, in **exit**
>       compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 187, in reraise
>       raise value   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 2223, in _flush
>       flush_context.execute()   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py",
>   line 389, in execute
>       rec.execute(self)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py",
>   line 548, in execute
>       uow   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py",
>   line 181, in save_obj
>       mapper, table, insert)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py",
>   line 835, in _emit_insert_statements
>       execute(statement, params)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 945, in execute
>       return meth(self, multiparams, params)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py",
>   line 263, in _execute_on_connection
>       return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)   File
>   "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 1053, in _execute_clauseelement
>       compiled_sql, distilled_params   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 1189, in _execute_context
>       context)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 1394, in _handle_dbapi_exception
>       exc_info   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 203, in raise_from_cause
>       reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 186, in reraise
>       raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 1182, in _execute_context
>       context)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py",
>   line 470, in do_execute
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py",
>   line 146, in execute
>       result = self._query(query)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py",
>   line 296, in _query
>       conn.query(q)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 781, in query
>       self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)   File
>   "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 942, in _read_query_result
>       result.read()   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 1138, in read
>       first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 906, in _read_packet
>       packet.check_error()   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 367, in check_error
>       err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/err.py",
>   line 120, in raise_mysql_exception
>       _check_mysql_exception(errinfo)   File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/colp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/err.py",
>   line 112, in _check_mysql_exception
>       raise errorclass(errno, errorvalue) sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a
>   session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely)
>   (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails (`colp`.`user_project`, CONSTRAINT
>   `user_project_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `projects`
>   (`id`))') [SQL: 'INSERT INTO user_project (user_id, role_id) VALUES
>   (%s, %s)'] [parameters: (1, 1)]

Any idea what I am doing wrong in this code

Comment: What the significance of `role_id` in association table? If its not mandatory to have then you see my answer below.

Comment: @Pradeepb I need to have the role_id. In reality, it should be a third foreign key to define permission for each user in every individual project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out a work around inspired by @Pradeepb previous response where he found that the code works only if new objects where defined. Not sure it is the best but it works.
This was achieved by modifying the UserProject class by adding a constructor

```
class UserProject(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_project'
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id'), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    user = db.relationship("User", backref="parent_assocs")
    project = db.relationship("Project", backref="assoc")

def __init__(self, project, user, role):
    self.project_id = project.id
    self.user_id = user.id
    self.role_id = role.id
```

to add an association using existing resource from DB I have used the code

```
prj = Project.query.first()
usr = User.query.first()
asso = UserProject(project = prj, user=usr, role_id =1)
```

Comment: More details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292726/how-to-properly-use-association-proxy-and-ordering-list-together-with-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 1):

After analyzing the problem for the error, I got to know that, it is working only when you create a new user(object),a new/existing project(object) and then if you associate, it will work fine. I got it working, when I did like below:

```
prj = Project(status=True //with other parameters) or prj = Project.query.first()
usr = User(is_admin=True //with other parameters)
asso = UserProject(role_id =1)
asso.user = usr
prj.users.append(asso)
```

But If I try to do the same with existing objects, I get same error as yours. May be this helps for further investigation :)

Comment: That was useful; I figured out that adding existing data is successful using different method.

Comment: That's great. You can post it as an answer for your question.